# Overriding sass media query mixins

Tags: sass, media-queries, mixins

I'm having trouble getting style to change as set within my media query mixing includes. I'm writing mobile first style then declaring the styles for larger screens within these media queries.

At the top of the doc I have.

```css
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == medium {
    @media (min-width: em(480)) { @content; }
  }
}


@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == large {
    @media (min-width: em(800)) { @content; }
  }
}
```

Then throughout I have styles written like this:

```css
.col-1-4 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

    @include breakpoint(medium) {
        width: 50%;
        padding-right: em(10);

        &:nth-child(2n) {  
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: em(10);   
        }

    }

    @include breakpoint(large) {
        width: 25%;

        &:nth-child(4n) { 
            padding-right: 0;   
        }
   }

}
```

The style for large show up at the desired `min-width` but not the medium styles.

If I switch the mixing at the top to:

```css
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == large {
    @media (min-width: em(800)) { @content; }
  }
}

@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == medium {
    @media (min-width: em(480)) { @content; }
  }
}
```

The styles change at `min-width` `medium` but not `large`.

How can I have the styles I want to take affect at the desired min-width?

My compiled CSS looks like this:

```css
.col-1-4 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0; }
  @media (min-width: 50em) {
    .col-1-4 {
      width: 25%; }
      .col-1-4:nth-child(4n) {
        padding-right: 0; } }
```

If I swap the mixins at the top it only compiles the one written at the top.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What does the compiled CSS look like?

Comment: I'll amend the question and add the compiled css

Comment: Yes, for some reason it only compiles with the media query mixin I write at the top of the document. I'm using a gui called hammer for mac to compile my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining your breakpoint mixin twice, which is causing the first one to be overwritten.

```
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == medium {
    @media (min-width: em(480)) { @content; }
  } @else if $point == large {
    @media (min-width: em(800)) { @content; }
  }
}
```